# ZendFramework autoRouting don't work

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
// The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

I've created a TestController.php with class TestController there is a method indexAction, but i can't execute it using this route, if I write /application/index/test or /application/index/index - its all okay, but if I change the controller to Test it don't work, I mean /application/test/test or /application/test/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the new controller to the controllers['invokables'] config section in Application's module.config.php:

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Test' => 'Application\Controller\TestController',
        ),
    ),
```